# publishing wsdl with gSOAP stand-alone server?

Tags: c++, gsoap

Now, I developed a gSOAP stand-alone server on 8080 port and it's working for SOAP RPC.

But I want to return **wsdl** content of a **wsdl** file in my file system when clients request for getting wsdl on the 8080 port.

what I can do to return wsdl to clients?

Comment: After a bad time, I find the solution on online gSOAP user guide :http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.10

Answer (score 1):

I used xd tool to generate a embbed version of my wsdl and store it a wsdl.h file with this command line (I`m doing this in my CMakeList.txt):

```
${GSOAP_ROOT_DIR}/bin/win32/xd -dwsdl ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${SOAP_NAME_SERVICE}.wsdl > ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wsdl.h
```

After that, I implemented this function, that can be better to lead with parameters in GET request:

```
int http_get(struct soap *soap)
{
  soap_response(soap, SOAP_HTML); // HTTP response header with text/html
  soap_send(soap, (const char*)wsdl);
  soap_end_send(soap);
  return SOAP_OK;
}
```

So, I configure this function to lead with all GET commands received by gSoap:

```
.
.
.
struct soap soap;
soap_init(&soap);
soap.fget = http_get;
.
.
.
```

Then, when your server receive a HTTP/GET request, your function will be called and send  the wsdl file. If you want, you can read WSDL file at runtime and send in soap_send() instead to embbed WSDL in your code like I did.